# How can I use the multiply blend mode on a canvas in real time?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, webgl

**Edit as of 2016**: The "multiply" value is implemented for [globalCompositeOperation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/globalCompositeOperation).  The performance is more than sufficient for real-time graphics.

---

Essentially, I have two canvases (one is an invisible canvas used for drawing) and I want to blend the invisible canvas onto the visible one with the multiply blend mode.

`Context.globalCompositeOperation` does not include multiply (though it should, in my opinion) and using `imageData` to manually blend the canvases is too slow (I need to be able to do this at 60fps).

Is there any faster method I could use to blend the canvases?  I believe this could be done using **WebGL**, but I have no experience using it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

WebGL's blend modes do not include multiplication (of the source and destination), either. However, you can perform the multiply operation efficiently using WebGL's render-to-texture capabilities:

1. Let your visible canvas be a WebGL canvas.
2. Create two textures; call them "source" and "destination".
3. Render your invisible-canvas content to the "source" texture; this can be done either using WebGL drawing operations directly (using no extra canvas) or by uploading your 2D invisible canvas's contents to the texture (this is a built-in operation):

   ```
   var sourceTexture = gl.createTexture()
   gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, sourceTexture)
   gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, sourceCanvas)
   // ...also set texture filters — see any WebGL tutorial...
   ```
4. Render the other content to be multiplied to the "destination" texture.
5. Finally, targeting the actual visible canvas, use a fragment shader to multiply the "source" and "destination" textures. The techniques here are those used for **post-processing effects** — I recommend looking up [such a tutorial](http://ssp.impulsetrain.com/porterduff.html) or simple example. Briefly, to apply a fragment shader to the entire canvas, you draw a **full-screen quad** - geometry that covers the entire viewport. The vertex shader is trivial, and the fragment shader would be like:

   ```
   varying vec2 texCoord;
   uniform sampler2D sourceTexture;
   uniform sampler2D destTexture;
   void main(void) {
     gl_FragColor = texture2D(sourceTexture, texCoord) * texture2D(destTexture, texCoord);
   }
   ```

If you want to do multiple *overlapping* multiply-blends per frame, then if there are no more than, say, 8, you can expand the above procedure to multiply several textures; if there are lots, you will need to do multiple stages of multiplying two textures while rendering to a third and then exchanging the roles.

If you would like a more specific answer, then please expand your question with more details on how many, and what kind of, graphics you are multiplying together.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I am extremely new to WebGL and need some help with the code. I've done some research and found that gl.texSubImage2D can be used to copy canvas contents into a webGL texture.  I was thinking to do something like gl.texSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D,0,0,0,640,480,GL_COLOR_INDEX,type,imageData).  However, I am not sure which type to use.  Also, I have no idea how to approach the shader part.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: @user1175802 I've added some specific sample code to answer your questions. Broadly, I recommend looking up a WebGL tutorial on postprocessing effects (as most of the code would be similar) and then adapting it to your needs.