# Blending two images with html5 canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas, alphablending

I need to draw 2 variations of the same image on top of each other, whose alpha values add up to 1.

For example :
- `imageA` has an alpha of `0.4`, while `imageB` has an alpha of `0.6`.
- The desired result is a completely opaque image (alpha of `1.0` for each pixel), which appears as a 60% blend of `imageB`, and a 40% blend of `imageA`.

However, I believe that the html5 canvas by default uses a blend mode other than add on alpha blended images, so two things drawn with alphas below 1 will not add up to 1.
 I've tried all the different compositing modes, along with the Adobe blend modes, but none of them have the desired result.
A simple test case is to draw a magenta rect twice, both with alpha of `0.5`. My desire is for the resulting pixels to be `rgb(255, 0, 255)`. However, the result is slightly transparent.

Does anyone know some way of achieving this result?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

• If you look at the canvas'context2D specification about the default blending mode ('source-over'):

http://dev.w3.org/fxtf/compositing-1/#simplealphacompositing

You'll see the formula used is ( i renamed the variables for clarity) :

```
colorOut = prevColor x prevAlpha + newColor x newAlpha x (1 - prevAlpha)
```

And for resulting alpha :

```
αlphaOut = prevAlpha + newAlpha x (1 - prevAlpha)
```

Notice that,
   a) unexpectedly, the formula is not linear (due to : newAlpha x (1 - prevAlpha) factor ).
   b) a point has *both* smaller r,g,b values *and* reduced alpha. So when re-using it, it
will contribute for square(0.6)==0.36 to the final image.  (...completely counter-intuitive...)

• So what does happen for your 60% / 40% draws ?

1) image A is drawn with alpha = 60%. 
The formula above gives :

```
 colorOut = color_A * 0.6 ;
 alphaOut = 0.6 ;
```

2) image B is drawn with alpha = 40%

```
 colorOut = color_A * 0.6 * 0.6 + color_B x 0.4 x (0.4);
 alphaOut = 0.6 + 0.4 * 0.4;
```

So final formula is ==>

```
 colorOut = 0.36 * color_A + 0.16 * color_B ;
 alphaOut = 0.76 ;
```

You see that's not *at all* the 60/40 mix you expected.

• How to fix ?

1) You can do it by hand using getImageData / putImageData. Be aware of the Cross-Origin issue : if your images don't come from your domain, their imageData will be empty.  For performances, bet on a 50+ slow-down factor compared to the canvas (= the GPU) doing the job. 'real time' (=60fps) might not be possible depending on image size/computing power/browser. But you have full control.

2) But if you now look at the 'ligther' composite mode, it seems we have our guy :

http://dev.w3.org/fxtf/compositing-1/#porterduffcompositingoperators_plus

Formula is now :

```
colorOut = prevColor x prevAlpha + newColor x newAlpha
```

And for resulting alpha :

```
 αlphaOut = prevAlpha + newAlpha
```

You see that this is a simple 'plus' operator, perfect for your requirement.
So solution is :
  - save ctx.
  - set lighter composite mode.
  - draw first image at 60% alpha.
  - draw second image at 40% alpha.
  - restore ctx.

Last words : if you want to check that the final alpha is right (==255), use that kind of function :

```
 function logAlpha(ctx,x,y) {
    var imDt = ctx.getImageData(x,y,1,1).data;
    if (!(imDt[0] || imDt[1] || imDt[2])) console.log('null point. CORS issue ?'); 
    console.log(' point at (' +x+ ',' +y+ ') has an alpha of ' + imDt[3] ) ;
 }
```

Comment: 'lighter' worked for me. Thanks so much! Very informative answer.